# how to perform neo4j cypher code formatting

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way/website/sublime plugin etc, to format cypher code (make it align and tidy)?

Same as this site is doing for javascript for example:
http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 3):

While not perfect, here is what I have been doing. (hopefully others will jump in and improve it)

```js
var Cypher = document.body.innerText
Cypher = Cypher.replace(/(?:\s*(OPTIONAL MATCH|MATCH|WHERE|WITH|RETURN|DETACH DELETE|DELETE|UNWIND|CASE)\s*)/gi, function(match) {
  return '\n' + match.toUpperCase() + ' '
});

Cypher = Cypher.replace(/(?:\s*(AND|NOT|DISTINCT)\s*)/gi, function(match) {
  return ' ' + match.toUpperCase().trim() + ' '
});

Cypher = Cypher.replace(/(?:\s*(\w+)\(\s*)/gi, function(match) {
  return ' ' + match.toUpperCase().trim()
});

document.body.innerText = Cypher
```

```html
match (n), (n)--(m) where n.car=1 and not n.id="rawr" with n.name return collect(n) as cars
```

([JSFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/cp9ngzge/))